# JotForm onchange event post to ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an interesting dilemma that I am trying to solve and I can't quite wrap my head around it properly. I am using some source code from JotForms and in a section it has:

```
 <div id="cid_51" class="form-input jf-required">
      <div style="width:100%; text-align:Left;">
        <iframe onload="widgetFrameLoaded(51)" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowTransparency="true" class="custom-field-frame" id="customFieldFrame_51" src="" style="border:none;width:400px; height: 50px;">
        </iframe>
        <div class="widget-inputs-wrapper">
          <input id="input_51" class="form-hidden widget-required form-widget" type="hidden" name="q51_dropdownOrganization" value="" />
          <input id="widget_settings_51" class="form-hidden form-widget-settings" type="hidden" value="%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22list%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22September%5Cn%20Saturday%2C%20September%2026%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Wednesday%2C%20September%2030%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5CnOctober%5Cn%20Saturday%2C%20October%203%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Wednesday%2C%20October%207%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Saturday%2C%20October%2010%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Wednesday%2C%20October%2014%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Saturday%2C%20October%2017%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Wednesday%2C%20October%2021%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Saturday%2C%20October%2024%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Wednesday%2C%20October%2028%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Saturday%2C%20October%2031%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5CnNovember%5Cn%20Wednesday%2C%20November%204%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Saturday%2C%20November%207%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Wednesday%2C%20November%2011%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Saturday%2C%20November%2014%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Wednesday%2C%20November%2018%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Saturday%2C%20November%2021%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5CnDecember%5Cn%20Wednesday%2C%20December%202%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Wednesday%2C%20December%209%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Saturday%2C%20December%2012%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Wednesday%2C%20December%2016%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Saturday%2C%20December%2019%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5CnJanuary%5Cn%20Wednesday%2C%20January%206%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Saturday%2C%20January%209%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Wednesday%2C%20January%2013%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Saturday%2C%20January%2016%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Wednesday%2C%20January%2020%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Saturday%2C%20January%2023%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Wednesday%2C%20January%2027%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Saturday%2C%20January%2030%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5CnFebruary%5Cn%20Wednesday%2C%20February%203%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Saturday%2C%20February%206%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Wednesday%2C%20February%2010%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Saturday%2C%20February%2013%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Wednesday%2C%20February%2024%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5CnMarch%5Cn%20Wednesday%2C%20March%202%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Saturday%2C%20March%205%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Wednesday%2C%20March%209%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Saturday%2C%20March%2012%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Wednesday%2C%20March%2016%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Saturday%2C%20March%2019%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Wednesday%2C%20March%2023%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Saturday%2C%20March%2026%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Wednesday%2C%20March%2030%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5CnApril%5Cn%20Saturday%2C%20April%202%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Wednesday%2C%20April%206%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Wednesday%2C%20April%2013%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Saturday%2C%20April%2016%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Wednesday%2C%20April%2027%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Saturday%2C%20April%2030%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5CnMay%5Cn%20Wednesday%2C%20May%204%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Saturday%2C%20May%207%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Wednesday%2C%20May%2011%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20Saturday%2C%20May%2014%5Cn%20%203%3A00-3%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A10-3%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A20-3%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A30-3%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A40-3%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%203%3A50-4%3A00%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A00-4%3A10%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A10-4%3A20%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A20-4%3A30%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A30-4%3A40%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A40-4%3A50%20pm%5Cn%20%204%3A50-5%3A00%20pm%22%7D%5D"
          data-version="2" />
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
         setTimeout(function()
            {
              var _cFieldFrame = document.getElementById("customFieldFrame_51");
              _cFieldFrame.src = "//widgets.jotform.io/dynamicDropdowns/?qid=51&ref=" + encodeURIComponent(window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host);
              _cFieldFrame.addClassName("custom-field-frame-rendered");
             }, 0);
        </script>
      </div>
 </div>
```

When the drop down element gets rendered, it renders something like this:

```
    <div id="dropdownsContainer">

        <select class="dd-0 ">
            <option value="September">September</option>
        </select>
        <select class="dd-0 dd-1 ">
            <option value="Saturday, September 26">Saturday, September 26</option>
        </select>
        <select class="dd-0 dd-1 dd-2 ">
            <option value="3:00-3:10 pm">3:00-3:10 pm</option>
        </select>

    </div>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is, that based on a change of the drop down select, it pushes it to a php script.

This is the JQuery code being used:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dd-0").on('change', function(){
        var matchvalue = $(this).val(); // this.value
        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'slider.php',
            data: { matchvalue: matchvalue },
            type: 'post'
        }).done(function(responseData) {
            console.log('Done: ', responseData);
        }).fail(function() {
            console.log('Failed');
        });
    });
});
```

One of the issues I am having is that in the console it's logging:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of null

I've tried various different ways and yet still noting gets me passed this message. What is it that I am missing? Could someone please advise as to why the code is throwing the error and not passing the onchange selected?